# How to transform SQL code into a measure?

Tags: ms-access, powerbi, measure

Right now i am using 3 CSV  files ( appointment, Person and Referral ) to calculate what i have called as KPI4, KPI5 and KPI6.

I import them into an Access Database that run some SQL queries.  I want to automate this proces a bit and create a measure for these KPI's and just upload/update the 3 csv files and the POWER BI report just get updated.

For example for KPI4 I have the following SQL's queries

First and the main one but which refers to z_KPI8_part1 :

```sql
SELECT
    Person.LPTID, Person.ccgName, Person.Caseload, t1.FTDate, 
    t1.SERVICEID, Person.LTCondition, Referral.Caseload, *
FROM
    Person
    INNER JOIN ((SELECT SERVICEID,FTDate
                 FROM z_KPI8_part1) AS t1 
    INNER JOIN Referral
        ON t1.SERVICEID = Referral.SERVICEID)
        ON Person.LPTID = Referral.LPTID;
```

**z_KPI8_part1** which referrs to z_FirstTreatmentDate :

```sql
SELECT
    z_FirstTreatmentDate.SERVICEID, Min(z_FirstTreatmentDate.FTDate) AS FTDate,
    Max(Appointment.ATTENDANCE) AS ATTENDANCE
FROM
    Appointment
    INNER JOIN z_FirstTreatmentDate
        ON (Appointment.SERVICEID = z_FirstTreatmentDate.SERVICEID) AND
           (Appointment.Appointment = z_FirstTreatmentDate.FTDate)
WHERE 
    (((z_FirstTreatmentDate.FTDate) Between [forms]![frmMain]![txtFTDateFrom] And
    [forms]![frmMain]![txtFTDateTo]))
GROUP BY
    z_FirstTreatmentDate.SERVICEID;
```

**z_FirstTreatmentDate** :

```sql
SELECT
    Appointment.SERVICEID, Min(Appointment.APPOINTMENT) AS FTDate,
    Min(Appointment.APPTYPE) AS APPTYPE
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM Appointment
     WHERE
         (Appointment.APPTYPE=02 OR Appointment.APPTYPE=03 OR Appointment.APPTYPE=05) AND
         (Appointment.ATTENDANCE='5' OR Appointment.ATTENDANCE='6')
    ) AS [%$##@_Alias]
GROUP BY
    Appointment.SERVICEID;
```

In theory KPI4 is First Appointment Date when client's  Session Type ( APPTYPE )is one of the following: 2,3,5
And

- Attendance Status is one of the following: 5 and 6.

From my method i am not getting anywhere near the numbers i get from Access database.

Please help me or guide me

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? You've tagged it, but your question only mentions Microsoft Access.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You seem to have two ways of getting numbers that should be equivalent but are not. You are showing us one of these ways. We don't know anything about the other one. Are you showing us the working one or the not working one? How does the other one work? What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: So this is the working one, from Access,  the first one is the one where it give me KPI4 figures.

i am willing to create a measure based on this SQL that will result the same figures and get rid of this Access queries ? because on access i just import these 3 csv files and run the first code and get the KPI4 figures

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result as text tables.